# C++ typedef error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, typedef

```
bool CInetWrapper::OpenFtpConnection (LPCTSTR lpszServerName)
{
    // internetconnect(inet_open,'ftp.site.ru',port,'login','pass',INTERNET_SERVICE_FTP,INTERNET_FLAG_PASSIVE,0);



    if (OpenInternet() && m_hConnection == NULL)
        // (HINTERNET,LPCSTR,INTERNET_PORT,LPCSTR,LPCSTR,DWORD,DWORD,DWORD);
        typedef HINTERNET (__stdcall* InternetConnect_)(HINTERNET,LPCSTR,INTERNET_PORT,LPCSTR,LPCSTR,DWORD,DWORD,DWORD);
        InternetConnect_ ic = (InternetConnect_)helper.GetProcAddressEx("wininet.dll", "InternetConnectA");
        m_hConnection = ic(
        m_hInternet,
        lpszServerName? lpszServerName:
            m_lpszServerName? m_lpszServerName: "localhost",
        INTERNET_DEFAULT_FTP_PORT,
        m_login,
        m_password,
        INTERNET_SERVICE_FTP,
        0,
        0);


    return CheckError(m_hConnection != NULL);
}
```

and compiler say: 1>------ Build started: Project: klstart, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  HTTPReader.cpp
1>c:\u\admin\visual studio 2010\projects\klstart\klstart\httpreader.cpp(100): error C2065: 'InternetConnect_' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\u\admin\visual studio 2010\projects\klstart\klstart\httpreader.cpp(100): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'helper'
What i write wrong?

Comment: No meaningful explanation can be derived from what you posted. Whatever is causing this, it is somewhere else. Provide more context. Does the call through `ic` really follows immediately after the declaration of `ic`, as in the code above? I kinda doubt it (the code is aligned differently...)

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to wrap the true branch of your `if` into a compound statement.

Basically, the problem is the same as in this piece of code

```
if (some_condition)
  typedef int MyType;
  MyType i; // ERROR: `MyType` is undeclared identifier
  ...
```

In the above simple example the imaginary "author" wanted to do this

```
if (something)
{
  typedef int MyType;
  MyType i; 
  ...
}
```

but he forgot to put those `{}` there and ended up with something completely different. You made the same mistake in your code.

Since you didn't create a compound statement after `if` (using the `{}`) the only part that is included into the true branch of that `if` is your `typedef` and nothing else. That branch with that lone `typedef` is a separate local scope that ends immediately after that `if`. This means that after your `if` typename `InternetConnect_` is no longer known.

Either place your `typedef` before your `if`, or wrap the true branch into a pair of `{}`.

Answer (score -1):

try using `#include <cstdlib>`

or try a using struct, would be more simple and easy to follow, less chance of error.

Comment: I'm add this header, but no changes :(. Not compiling. This code run typedef BOOL (__stdcall* InternetCloseHandle_)(HINTERNET);
 InternetCloseHandle_ _InternetCloseHandle = (InternetCloseHandle_)helper.GetProcAddressEx("wininet.dll", "InternetCloseHandle");
 if (m_hInternet) 
  _InternetCloseHandle(m_hInternet);